# SQL - SUM two columns with a date range on one of the columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, reporting-services, report

First off its been a long week and I'm having a moment e.g. I just can't figure this out but I know its straight forward.

I have a CTE with a query for a GL Detail and one for Budget which are bought together to display all the details needed for a report.

For example the GL detail bring back the actual amount from a date range such as 2019-01-01 and 2019-04-01
and the budget part brings back the budget for each month so the date range is 2019-01-01 and 2019-12-01 as I need to sum up the total budget in a report.

Using an iif expression in SSRS the report shows the actuals up to the month a user select (there is on a to_date parameter)such as April then the report shows actual from Jan and then budget from May to Dec. I need to show the total of budget for the 12 month which is straight forward as I have bought each month amount back.

My question is I need to sum the GL actual amount for the months selected in by the user Jan to April and the remaining budget amounts May to Dec. For some reason I just can't work it out in my head.

Edit - I'm using 
postgresql 
SSRS - Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services
columns are in GL is gldetail.amount and for Budget budget.amount_budget - I have a column in both gldetail and budget queries which is called post_date.

Comment: Your question needs sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out -

```
 ,case 
    when src.post_date <= src._to_date then src.amount
    when src.post_date > src._to_date then src.amount_budget
    end as actual_budget_total
```

Then in the report sum the actual_budget_total